# Splitting a String using regex in c#

Tags: c#, split, character

I have a program to compare text files. Takes in 2 files spits out 1. The input files have lines of data similar to this

```
tv_rocscores_DeDeP005M3TSub.csv FMR: 0.0009 FNMR: 0.023809524 SCORE: -4  Conformity: True
tv_..............P006............................................................
tv_..............P007............................................................
```

etc etc.

For my initial purposes, I was splitting the lines based on spaces, to get the respective values. However, for the first field, tv_rocscores_DeDeP005M3TSbu.csv i only need P005 and not the rest. I cannot opt for position number as well, because the position of P005 in the phrase is not the same for every file.

Any advise on how i split this so that i can identify my first field with only P005??

Comment: Is it always P005? What's the pattern here?

Comment: If you got a pattern as @germi was looking for you could extract the value via a regex.

Comment: That's just one line. I have from P001 to P100 in my text files. This was just for an example.

Comment: Please let me edit the question for better understanding

Comment: Without using regex: get a new line, find first occurrence of `.csv`, go back until you read `Pxxx`, take `xxx`. Should not be hard.

Comment: Actually, i was using regex for something else(to match a pattern). So, that goes easy with my grouping. Anyhoo, Thank you very much to all you guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a bit unclear. If you're looking for *pattern*, say *"P + three digits"*, e.g. *"P005"* you can use *regular expressions*:

```
  String str = @"tv_rocscores_DeDeP005M3TSub.csv FMR: 0.0009 FNMR: 0.023809524 SCORE: -4  Conformity: True";

  String[] parts = str.Split(' ');
  parts[0] = Regex.Match(parts[0], @"P\d\d\d").Value; // <- "P005"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Dmitry. Lemme test that out please. :)

Comment: This worked like a charm for me. This is actually easier for me to use in my program. And so i am accepting this answer. Thank you very much again

Answer (score 1):

To extract the desired part I would try something like this:

```
 var parts = str.Split(' ');
 var number = Regex.Match(parts[0], ".*?(?<num>P\d+).*?").Groups["num"].Value;
```

Or if you know its only three digits you could change the regular expression to `.*?(?<num>P\d{3}).*?`

Hope that solves your problem :)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. I already got an answer(same as yours). This goes well with my application. Thanks for taking time to answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

How about just checking if the first field contains `P005`?

```
bool hasP005 = field1.Contains("P005");
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer my question. I got my answer. Have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clear. Can't you just replace the first field with your string?

```
string[] parts = str.Split(' ');
parts[0] = "P005";
```

Comment: I am sorry my question wasn't clear. I have a program to compare two text files and subtract the respective fields (based on the first field tv_roc....P005...)

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer my question

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to try field the field that contains that string? if so then you can use some linq

```
var field = s.Split(' ').Where(x => x.Contains("P005")).ToList()[0];
```

Comment: No worries. Thank you very much for taking time to answer my question. I got my answer. Thanks again